# Inserting a combobox in a datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, datagridcomboboxcolumn

C#

```
 MainDataContext db = new MainDataContext();
var cat = from p in db.Categories
                      select p;
categoriesComboBox.ItemsSource = cat;
            categoriesComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
            categoriesComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "CatName";
```

XAML

```
<Custom:DataGridComboBoxColumn                                    
Width="1*"                                  x:Name="categoriesComboBox" 
Header="Category"
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Category}"
SelectedValuePath="ID"
DisplayMemberPath="CatName"
/>
```

Now the thing is i can see the name in the comobox when it loads... when i click on the combobox the dropdown shows me MainDataContext.Category for each and every item...

when i click on any of the drop down items.. its select the correct value and.. showing me in the combobox...

[image: When the grid is loaded...]
[image: After the i double click on that column..]

Answer (score 0):

You should not set `categoriesComboBox.ItemsSource = cat;` yourself, try doing it with the data context: `categoriesComboBox.DataContext = cat`. Anyway, you've got the needed bindings in your XAML.

Hope that this is your actual problem (since I didn't manage to understand what the problem is from your question).

---

Edit: from your images, you need to specify a `DataTemplate` for your type `MainContext.Category`. Without it, the default template is used, which just outputs the string representation.

Comment: actually i am not able to do it can you please give me any simple example. :)

Comment: @siddhartha: look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), there are some examples there. or [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html).